# Why Debian Jessie is turned off instead of rebooting after installing qemu-kvm?

Tags: debian, systemd, kvm, qemu

I'm using a new stable Debian Jessie (minimal installation without DE and standard utilities).

First of all, I set 'enabled' for Intel virtualisation in BIOS and installed qemu-kvm as usual:

`# aptitude install uml-utilities bridge-utils qemu-kvm virtinst libvirt-bin`

Then I configured bridge in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
 auto br0
 iface br0 inet dhcp
 bridge_ports eth1
 bridge_fd 9
 bridge_hello 2
 bridge_maxage 12
 bridge_stp off
```

Then I installed virtual guest, which works fine.

The problem is that when I want to reboot my host system, I type `reboot`, but computer completely shuts down (all HDD, power supply, fans etc) and then on again 3 seconds later.

Previously (with Debian Wheezy) the same computer could restart without completely turning off.

Other symptoms:

1. Message' KVM: disabled by BIOS' during system start (but not every time). Intel virtualisation and VT-d options in BIOS still enabled.
2. Message 'Running guests on default URI: no running guests'. 
   This message disappears since I edit /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/libvirt-guests.service:
   `RemainAfterExit=no`

But my computer still completely shuts down when every reboot.